# Need to delete files in session in selenium grid 4

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm using selenium grid 4 enable managed downloads with parallel browsers. However what I need is to delete the file from that session in this URL `/session/{sessionId}/se/files`.

For this purpose I'm doing the following -

```
HttpRequest delRequest = new HttpRequest(org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpMethod.DELETE,
 String.format("/session/%s/se/files", sessionId1));
HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(delRequest);
```

But I get this error -

```
404: {"value":{"error":"unknown command","message":"unknown command: unknown command: session/041ee5c716ac3bd31a7c270080700fcc/se/files","stacktrace":"Backtrace:\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x007ADCE3+50899]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0073E111]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00645588]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00688311]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00687ADE]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00625391]\n\t(No symbol) [0x0062598E]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00625D6A]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00A13EAE+2566302]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00A492B1+2784417]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00A4327C+2759788]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00845740+672048]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00748872]\n\t(No symbol) [0x00624FEA]\n\t(No symbol) [0x006249EF]\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00A6BBCC+2926012]\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x75B80099+25]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77177B6E+286]\n\tRtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77177B3E+238]\n"}}
```